# ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed and ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle

in sqlnet.ora file:

when i have **SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)**

i **can't** connect by PL/SQL developer arises "ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed"
,but **can** connect by command line

when i have **SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)**

i **can't** connect

```
>sqlplus / as sysdba
```

arises "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"

,but **can** connect by PL/SQL developer and command line when i supply username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server administrator may not have setup NTS authentication on the database. You can't simply ask for your credentials to be authenticated by NTS in your client SQLNET.ORA file without agreement on the server side.

Comment: Oracle DB is installed on my computer...So sqlnet.ora file was changed on the server side...But as I found I did not have some permissions on my computer especially some ports an so on(I do not know exactly) was blocked for my IP...After my computer IP was inserted into admins by net administrators, the problem was solved...But still do not know why?Does Oracle uses some services or something additional at this time?I don not know...

Comment: Ok, that explains some more. Yes, you need to have special rights and connectivity to Active Directory to get this working. I'm not a DBA or Windows admin, so I'm not sure of all the steps involved. Sounds like someone on your side does, though. It would be nice to know exactly what needed to happen, for the sake of everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same issue.

When I made the change to
`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)` to resolve the ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed.

I was then unable to connect with the sysdba privilege.

ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when `sqlplus / as sysdba`

**The Solution:**

I was able to find out, I could still connect as sysdba with the following command:

From within sqlplus:

```
connect sys as sysdba
```

From command line:

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

In both cases, you will be prompted for your password.  The password will be the same as your password that you setup for the SYSTEM user during the windows Oracle install.

Now you are connected with the sysdba rights you were trying to get with  `sqlplus / as sysdba`.